# Jelastic maintenance windows & process across providers

Tags: jelastic

Does anyone know if all Jelastic providers have the same outage windows & process? I'm liking Jelastic for the simplicity but the last maintenance window caused issues for my application despite only impacting the dashboard (supposedly).

1. Are all Jelastic providers going to be down for maintenance at the same time?
2. Are the upgrade process/scripts uniform across the providers? i.e. provided by jelastic?

Cheers

Answer (score 2):

> Are all Jelastic providers going to be down for maintenance at the same time?

Jelastic releases are rolled out to most/all providers around the same time (i.e. within a period of a few weeks).

> Are the upgrade process/scripts uniform across the providers? i.e. provided by jelastic?

Jelastic development team engineers create the upgrade scripts and perform the upgrade process, so the actual upgrade experience should be approximately the same at every provider.

*Most* platform upgrades are targeted at improving the underlying platform (e.g. adding new dashboard features, core infrastructure etc.) and should not have any impact on your application servers.

Maintenance windows are announced to provide notification that some operations will be performed, because there is always a risk that something unforeseen can happen in such cases (if it could be guaranteed **zero** risk, there would be no need for any notification).

Just as you do with your own application, every Jelastic platform change is tested thoroughly in a dev environment, and the full upgrade process is simulated in a stage environment, so that as many issues as possible are identified and eliminated before it touches the live production platform - but software engineering is complex (as everyone reading stackoverflow appreciates) and there is no such thing as 100% error free software.

PS the fact that I can say exactly which environment you're referring to should tell you something about the number of environments affected. Unfortunately you were very unlucky in this instance, and Jelastic engineers are still investigating the exact details to identify root cause + will outline necessary steps to avoid a recurrence. Application uptime and stability is a **critical** issue to us all.